# Better way to override atomic property setter for ARC and thread-safe in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, overriding, setter

I have a class containing enum property, and I want to init its instances from plist file using method `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`. But the file may contain invalid values. The scenario is as follows:
In the file 'MyClass.h':

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FruitTag) {
    Apple   = 0,
    Banana  = 1,
    Orange  = 2,
    Unknown = 3
};

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property FruitTag tag;

@end
```

the plist file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Apple</string>
        <key>tag</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Banana</string>
        <key>tag</key>
        <string>1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Pineapple</string>
        <key>tag</key>
        <string>5</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

As you see, the last key value '5' is invalid for the max enum value is '3'! But the method `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` just set the value, no matter valid or not. So I want to override the setter, but the enum property is atomic! One more thing is: I want its getter and setter be safe in multi-thread scenario. Thinking about the two, I modified the code as:

In the file 'Myclass.h':

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FruitTag) {
    Apple   = 0,
    Banana  = 1,
    Orange  = 2,
    Unknown = 3
};

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
//@property FruitTag tag;

- (FruitTag)tag;
- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)aTag;

@end
```

And in the file 'Myclass.m':

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
{
    FruitTag tag;
}

- (FruitTag)tag
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        return tag;
    }
}

- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)aTag
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        if ((aTag < Apple) || (aTag > Unknown)) {
            tag = Unknown;
        } else {
            tag = aTag;
        }
    }
}

- (void)print
{
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSLog(@"the tag is: %d", tag);
    }
}

@end
```

Hmm, it looks odd, but does work as I test using the method `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`. But I am not sure about it: is it ok? thread-safe enough? any potential risk? or a better way to override is more welcome! thanks!

Comment: I do not simply add qualifier 'nonatomic' to the enum property, for I want the setter can accept a NSInteger parameter, instead of enum type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it looks odd? You've just manually implemented a "property" and added simple bounds checking – a good reason to implement a property yourself.

Is it thread-safe enough? Well it either is or it isn't, and `@synchronized` certainly makes it so. There might be more efficient, lower-level, ways of making the operations thread-safe; or you might even discover that it is "enough" to do nothing special; but unless you've identified a performance issue there is no need to go there - the code is simple and your intentions are clear.

HTH

Comment: Hmm, because there is no property named 'tag', while I using the method `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`. Does it work in all scenarios? (say, different versions of iOS.)  One more thing about thread-safe, in my code, is it ok when both getter and setter be called at the same time? `@synchronized` do the same work to the third method `print`?

Comment: `@property` is just a shorthand for two methods, you've just written the two methods - don't think of it as odd. Yes you've tweaked the type of the setter, but not in a bad way - maybe think of it as a *duck property* if that helps :-)

Comment: `@synchronized(self)` is a lock on `self` - the whole purpose of it is to deal with the case when two or more methods may be called at the same time (from different threads) and need to be forced to execute one at a time. So yes, you can call the setter, getter, and print methods at the same time and they'll execute sequentially (in some order).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend on such implementation:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t atomicSyncQueue;

@synthesize tag = _tag;

// @init time
_atomicSyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.YOUR_DEBUG_INFO", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

- (NSInteger)tag {
    __block NSInteger result = NO;
    
    dispatch_sync(self.atomicSyncQueue, ^{
        result = _tag;
    });
    
    return result;
}

- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)value {
    dispatch_async(self.atomicSyncQueue, ^{
        if (self->_tag != tag) {
            self->_tag = tag;

            // custom code:
        }
    });
}
```